Derivative of a sign-like function
Assume a function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ such that
$$f(x_1,x_2)=\begin{cases}
1 & x_2\le h(x_1,t) \\ 0 & x_2 > h(x_1,t)
\end{cases}$$.
I am trying to find the derivative of f in the distribution sense. After a lot of reading in several books my intuition is that the derivative in the distribution sense must be: $$-(\nabla h)^\perp\delta(x_2-h)$$
Where $\delta$ is the dirac distribution.
But i cannot prove it.
My idea was the following
Assume that w is the derivative in the distribution sense and g a test function then by definition $$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} w g dx= -\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f g' dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{h}^{\infty} g' dx_2 dx_1$$
Does anyone had a reference for the derivatives of those functions? Or any idea how to start?

Generally, if $D \subset \mathbb R^n$ is a region with smooth boundary then, for any test function $\varphi$ we have
$$\langle \nabla\mathbf{1}_D, \varphi \rangle = \int_{\partial D} (-\mathbf n) \varphi \, d\sigma,$$
where $\mathbf 1_D$ is the indicator function of $D,$ $\mathbf n$ is the outwards pointing unit normal on $\partial D,$ and $\sigma$ is the induced measure on $\partial D.$ We could denote this something like $\langle -\mathbf n \, \sigma, \varphi\rangle$ or $\langle -\mathbf n \, \delta_{\partial D}, \varphi\rangle$ with $\sigma$ or $\delta_{\partial D}$ be the boundary measure living only on $\partial D.$
In your case, $\sigma$ measures length on the boundary and
$$d\sigma=\sqrt{1+\partial_x h(x_1,t)^2}\,dx_1,$$
$$\mathbf n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\partial_{x_1} h(x_1,t)^2}}(-\partial_{x_1} h(x_1,t)\hat x_1 + \hat x_2),$$
where $\hat x_i$ is the unit vector in the $x_i$ direction.
This gives that
$$
\langle \nabla f, \varphi \rangle = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (-\partial_{x_1} h(x_1,t)\hat x_1 + \hat x_2) \, \varphi(x_1, h(x_1,t)) \, dx_1.
$$

@user1174736. Well, if we can find $g$ such that, on $\partial D,$ we have $g=0$ and $|\nabla g|=1,$ then we can write $\nabla f = \delta(g(x_1,x_2)).$
